# Domain name validation

Tags: jquery, regex

I want to validate a domain name in which the user should not be allowed to enter http:// or HTTP:// and www. and WWW. and it should accept the below conditions

```
1.xyz.com
2.xyz.co.in
3.xyz.com.in
4.mail.com.com
5.ma-il.com
6.ma-il.com.com
7.123.com
   mail2.com
   2mail.com
   mai2l.com
8.COM.COM.COM
9.mail.comm.com
10.mail.com.com.com.comc.com
11.mail.123.COM
12.123.123.com
13.MAIL.MA-1.COM  and some invalid domains are

mail.com.inn,mail.innn,123.comm,mail.comm.comm,mail.com.c-m.
```

Can someone pls help me to validate the domain field.

Comment: is that an exhaustive list of valid domains? If not, then what are the exact rules?

Comment: http://sqa.fyicenter.com/Online_Test_Tools/Domain_Name_Format_Validator.php

Comment: I referred the above link and got the conditions

Comment: there is so many answers with regexps for domain names, with tlds or without....

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
^([a-zA-Z0-9]([a-zA-Z0-9\-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?\.)+[a-zA-Z-]{2,6}$
```

Comment: The first character class there should not include digits as the first character of a label must be a letter only ie. [a-zA-Z]